# Image is not uploaded to server using retrofit in android

Tags: android, retrofit2, multipart

i am working on a app where i need to upload image on server i can not able to upload image on server using retrofit i don't no what is going a wrong with the using of same code i upload image in another app. following is my code .

```
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_GALLERY_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            uri = data.getData();
            if(EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                String filePath = getRealPathFromURIPath(uri, ProfileActivity.this);
                File file = new File(filePath);
                iv_user_profile_image.setImageURI(uri);

                Log.d(TAG, "Filename " + file.getName());

                RequestBody mFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
                MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), mFile);
                RequestBody filename = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), file.getName());
                RequestBody uid = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), loginStatusModal.getUser_id());

                WebClient uploadImage = ServiceGenerators.createService(WebClient.class);
                Call<UploadObject> fileUpload = uploadImage.uploadFile(mAuthorizationHeader,fileToUpload/*,uid*/);
                String abc = fileUpload.request().url().toString();
                fileUpload.enqueue(new Callback<UploadObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<UploadObject> call, Response<UploadObject> response) {
                        Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Response " + response.raw().message(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Success " + response.body().getStatus(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<UploadObject> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error " + t.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }else{
                EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, getString(R.string.read_file), READ_REQUEST_CODE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
        }
    }
```

this is my code for service call . every time when i rune the code it say

```
  Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 2 column 1 path $
```

this message is come 
following is my interface

```
@Multipart
@POST("/api/uploadimage")
Call<UploadObject> uploadFile(@Header("Authorization") String authorizationHeader,
                              @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

please tell me what is exactly wrong in this code 
any help is welcome .

Answer (score 0):

Your generated JSON is malformed. Get the output and test it with A service like https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to see where the problem is.

Your Retrofit call should probably look like the following:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/api/uploadimage")
Call<UploadObject> uploadFile(@Header("Authorization") String 
authorizationHeader, RequestBody file);


RequestBody typedFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
uploadImage.uploadFile(mAuthorizationHeader, typedFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Gson expecting an object, but is receiving a String, this is because the format of the JSON probably is wrong. The JSON has to start with

```
{
```

Or if you are using GSON for example, you can set:

```
.setLenient()
```

for accepting malformed JSON

**Nice coding!**

Comment: .setLenient() is used also json is valid but still this error come

Comment: Plese, show use, your JSON response, and we can tell you a little more about the format.

Comment: {
  "status": "success",
  "code": 2001,
  "image_path": "http://emr.nullplex.com/uploads/d41/d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e054858pm.jpg"
}

Comment: The JSON has to finish with ", and you have a ; alone. This is also an error

Comment: you can always use this website to validate / check your json response https://jsonlint.com/